# My ionic apk does not connect with webserver

Tags: android, web-services, ionic-framework

I have a problem with my app.

When I use `ionic serve` the app works correctly.

When I have my apk (`ionic cordova run --dev android  --verbose`), the app cannot connect with the webserver. The connection gives me 404 error.

I don't know why this happens.

I'm using Ionic.

My **config.xml**.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.joobis100342" version="0.1.80" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>Consultores de Empresas Nos</name>
    <description>
    Es una aplicación que brinda a los trabajadores activos del Grupo Consultores de Empresas la posibilidad de realizar determinadas operaciones, entre ellas, poder visualizar sus recibos de sueldos de manera on-line, comunicarse con alguna área de la empresa para obtener respuestas a sus consultas sobre liquidaciones, ausencias, entre otras funciones.
  </description>
    <author email="desarrollo.cde@gmail.com" href="https://www.consultoresdeempresas.com/">
      Jobiis Dev Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <feature name="StatusBar">
        <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar" />
    </feature>
    <gap:plugin name="com.adobe.plugins.gaplugin" />
    <platform name="android">
        <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />
        <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="~1.9.2">
        <variable name="SENDER_ID" value="898376791779" />
    </plugin>
</widget>
```

My app.js

```
// Ionic Starter App
// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
// 'starter.controllers' is found in controllers.js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services','ngCordova'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform,$http,$rootScope) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

        }
        if(window.StatusBar) {
            // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
    });
})
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('app', {
        url: "/app",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
        controller: 'AppCtrl',
        onExit: function(){
            $scope.logged = localStorage.getItem('logged');
            alert($scope.logged );
        }         
    })
    .state('app.login', {
        url: "/login",
        views: {
            'menuContent' :{
                templateUrl: "templates/lgin.html"
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.logout', {
        url: "/logout",
        views: {
            'menuContent' :{
                templateUrl: "templates/logout.html",
                controller: 'LogoutCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.index', {
        url: "/index",
        views: {
            'menuContent' :{
                templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
                controller: 'FrontCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.novedades', {
        url: "/novedades",
        views: {
            'menuContent' :{
                templateUrl: "templates/novedades.html"
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.noticia', {
        url: "/noticia",
        views: {
            'menuContent' :{
                templateUrl: "templates/noticia.html",
                controller: 'NoticiaCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.inbox', {
        url: "/inbox",
        views: {
            'menuContent' :{
                templateUrl: "templates/showInbox.html",
                controller: 'InboxCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.enviarMensaje', {
        url: "/enviarMensaje",
        views: {
            'menuContent' :{
                templateUrl: "templates/enviarMensaje.html"
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.responderMensaje', {
        url: "/responderMensaje/:msjId",
        views: {
            'menuContent' :{
                templateUrl: "templates/responderMensaje.html",
                controller: 'ResponseCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.llamenmeAdvice', {
        url: "/llamenmeAdvice",
        views: {
            'menuContent' :{
                templateUrl: "templates/llamenmeAdvice.html"
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.llamenme', {
        url: "/llamenme",
        views: {
            'menuContent' :{
                templateUrl: "templates/llamenme.html",
                controller: 'LlamenmeCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.contacto', {
        url: "/contacto",
        views: {
            'menuContent' :{
                templateUrl: "templates/contacto.html"
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.liquidaciones', {
        url: "/liquidaciones",
        views: {
            'menuContent' :{
                templateUrl: "templates/liquidaciones.html"
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.downloadLiquidacion', {
        url: "/downloadLiquidacion",
        views: {
            'menuContent' :{
                templateUrl: "templates/downloadLiquidacion.html",
                controller: 'LiquidacionCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.sendDocumentation', {
        url: "/sendDocumentation",
        views: {
            'menuContent' :{
                templateUrl: "templates/sendDocumentation.html",
                controller: 'DocumentationCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.manual', {
        url: "/manual",
        views: {
            'menuContent' :{
                templateUrl: "templates/manual.html",
                controller: 'ManualCtrl'
            }
        }
    });
    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/index');
})
.constant('serverURL', 'http://webservice.consultoresdeempresas.com:8080/profit_m_backend/')
//.constant('serverURL', 'http://172.16.11.124:9080/profit_m_backend/') /*'http://172.16.10.235:8080/profit_m_backend/' */
.constant('liquidacionURL', 'http://servicios.consultoresdeempresas.com/autogestion/liquidaciones/imprimir_phone/');
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "joobis",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "joobis: An Ionic project",
  "dependencies": {
    "cordova": "^8.0.0",
    "cordova-android": "7.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.5.6",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.3.3",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.3.2",
    "gulp-util": "^2.2.14",
    "karma": "^0.12.24",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.1.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.1.5",
    "shelljs": "^0.3.0",
    "phonegap-plugin-push": "~1.9.2"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    {
      "variables": {
        "SENDER_ID": "898376791779"
      },
      "locator": "phonegap-plugin-push"
    },
    {
      "locator": "https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git",
      "id": "phonegap-plugin-push"
    }
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "android"
  ],
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "phonegap-plugin-push": {
        "SENDER_ID": "898376791779"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can you help me, please? I don't know what I have to do.

Comment: In your AndroidManifest.xml file do you have the internet connection permission?<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: yes, i have the permission.